# Assigning NSString value to label

Tags: interface-builder, uitextfield, label

I have tried to apply the value from a NSString to a label in IB.  The problem im seeing, is that the value assigne to the label is:

```
UITextField: 0x6d4e0f0; frame = (7 86; 97 31); text = '2'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = CALayer: 0x6d4e210
```

I obviously would like to just see "2" rather than the whole UITextfield data.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

In your label say:

```
[label setText: theTextField.text];
```

Instead of:

```
[label setText: theTextField];
```

My guess is your passing the whole UITextField object, but you really just want to pass the .text part of it.

For your comment:

```
NSString date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", day, month, year];
```

Comment: COol that works.  Now if i have 3 NSStrings i wish to append together i.e. day - month - year.  How do i get the label to read= 2/3/1988 for example?

Comment: Sorry to nag, but how do you attach 3 numbers together?  Seperated by the "/" character.